# Cell with date greater than another cell with date

Tags: excel, date

I have tried using a variation of formulas mentioned in previous questions but can't find a way to make it work for me. I have a date in "X column" for the Due Date and a date in "Y column" for the Date Complete. I am trying to create a formula that will turn red when the Date Complete is greater than the Due Date. This will need to be a formula that can be repeated used as I add data weekly.

Comment: Did you try using a conditional formatting?

Comment: I tried everything possible that I could find online in regards to formulas and conditional formatting. I am by no means a pro at Excel but I did as much research and trying to do as much as I could before asking for help. Usually, I can figure it out for myself by looking online. I tried =IF, =COUNTIF and a couple of different conditional formatting options.

Comment: Oh and I also tried =DATE but failed at making it work.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use conditional formatting for this.

Go into conditional formatting, select "New Rule", then "Use a formula to determine which cells to format". If your due date is in column "A" and your completion date is in column "B", you would place the following formula in the box:
    =($A$1-$B$1)<0
Apply this formula to cell B1, and make your formatting changes (fill red).

If you copy this down, it should work for subsequent rows.

Comment: Thanks! I can get it to work in the cell I made the New Rule but it won't carry down to subsequent rows. I think it's because I copy/paste from a report ran online...I can't do this for each line after I copy/paste as that would take forever and be pointless. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: In the "rules manager window" (go to Conditional Formatting, then manage rules, you can apply it to whatever cells you want. You would currently have it in B1, but you can change it to B1:B50, or whatever number of rows you need.

Answer (score 0):

If column C is empty and Column A is your due date and Column B is your complete date, type this formula in column C:

```
=IF(A2<B2,"YES","NO")
```

Then do conditional formatting for text that contains "yes" for range C2:C50; assuming you have headings in Row 1.